# Angular 1/ ui-router 1 - is it recommended to pass a large object in params?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My `$state.go` :

`this.$state.go(transfer.project, params)`

where prams is an object that contains a large `project` object and `projectId` property number type.

The state :

```
.state({
  name: 'transfer.project',
  url: '/{projectId:int}',
  params: {
    project: null
  },
  component: 'projectTransfer'
})
```

And I recover the object in my component with:

```
this.project = this.$state.params.project
```

is it a good practice to spend a large object in params ?
Or if you know where is the source code that this in ui-route library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is only being passed by reference, so all that's really happening is an additional pointer is being created to it. Resource usage would be very minimal.

Comment: No problem on that?

Comment: No. There shouldn't be.

Comment: Do you have an idea of the source code that does this in ui-router?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but no, I'm not familiar with the source of UI router. JavaScript objects are always passed by reference. This isn't something that's unique to UI router.